# After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS unable to login with Ubuntu session

Tags: upgrade, login, 18.04

When trying to log into an Ubuntu session I see a flash of the desktop and immediately brought back to the login screen. I am able to use the generic GNOME session for the meantime but would like to use the layout of the newer version of Ubuntu.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you get a password error in your first attempt to enter password? I tried it and it happens. Once password incorrect is shown,press cancel,and log in again. It worked for me

Comment: Unfortunately, there was no password error.

Answer (score 6):

What I found is that gdm3 (GNOME login manager) is broken somehow especially with AMD GPU graphics. To get around it, remove it completely.

I also reinstalled LightDM login display manager.

Then I found that the default desktop was also broken and kept kicking me back out to the login screen when I tried to login, so I chose 'Ubuntu Unity' instead when I type in my username and password section in the now FIXED login manager. Everything now works.

To achieve this, here's what I did.

```
sudo apt purge lightdm -y
sudo apt install lightdm -y
```

A screen will pop up and ask you to choose lightdm or some other login manager. Choose lightdm.

```
sudo apt purge gdm3 -y # Get rid of gdm3, it's broken.
sudo reboot
```

On reboot, your login screen should now work. 
If not then unfortunately, you are like me because when I tried, I got kicked back to the login screen again after around 8 seconds. 
The GNOME Desktop Manager is also broken.

So from there, the login screen, click on the little wheel-like Ubuntu circle next to your name and choose Ubuntu Unity as the desktop, not Ubuntu or Wayland. From there on everything should just work.

Obviously there are some really bad incompatibilities with gdm3 and GNOME in general with AMD GPUs

If you don't have Unity installed, go back to the text login and run:

```
sudo apt install unity -y
```

Then reboot again when finished.

Now you should be able to select Unity desktop manager. 
GNOME desktop seems seriously broken for me. I hope they fix these bugs soon.

This issue is fixed for me now.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to 1804 from 1710 my login screen disappeared leaving the VT1 login. I then entered user name password and used "startx" to start a session and troubleshoot. My 1710 install had gnome + unity so was not standard.

Problem was fixed by using Synaptic to remove the last bit of lightdm (+ unity) and re-installing gdm which replaces lightdm in 1804. The display manager app is responsible for login and starting sessions.

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing that and reinstalled ubuntu-gnome desktop but the additional sessions are unavailable. Now I am just using the generic gnome desktop with the POP OS theme. As long I can log in then I guess no worries.

Answer (score 0):

It used to happen to me when I tampered with multiple GUIs (Gnome + KDE + Openbox, etc).

Try opening a TTY (Ctrl+Alt+F1 or Ctrl+Alt+F2), logging in, and on the terminal, delete/move the following folders:

```
    .gnome
    .gnome2
```

right on your home directory. Then restart and try logging in as usual.

Tell us what happened next!

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that, unfortunately, deleting the directories did not work.  I can of course still use GNOME, GNOME on Xorg but not Ubuntu or Ubuntu on Wayland.

Comment: I guess it is worth asking is there a way to reinstall the Ubuntu Gnome Desktop?